# Open inventory hotkey doesn't work in tight spot

Tags: factorio

I've always used `E` to bring up the inventory in Factorio.
However in the single player scenario `Tight spot` this key does nothing.
I'll start the game, buy some machines and supplies, start the game.
I can't do anything beyond that.

I also tried moving stuff to my toolbar.
But once the game starts, the toolbar disappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how the “Tight spot” scenario works.

You bought machines, but you also need to *place* the machines while in the initial “paused” condition, setting them up to work. Then when you push the “Start” button in the corner, they will run but you can't interact with them while they're working.

You have to design a factory that will run *without intervention* to meet the production goal.